# expo-store-review is automatically opening app store instead of asking for a rating

Tags: expo

I'm trying to implement [expo-store-review](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/storereview/), and want the popup asking for a star rating. Instead of getting a popup asking for a rating, it is just redirecting to the app store.

My component:

```
  import * as StoreReview from 'expo-store-review';

  componentDidMount() {
      StoreReview.requestReview();
  }
```

I've been searching for hours - hopefully some fresh eyes can spot the issue. Thanks!

UPDATE - I even tried putting in button with [this code](https://snack.expo.io/@notbrent/store-review?platform=ios), but when I click the button it again just opens the app store, instead of asking for a review in-app

UPDATE 2

```
`console.log(StoreReview)
console.log(StoreReview.requestReview)`
```

returns an object and a function, meaning they are both defined.

Comment: the provided expo example seems to be working.

Comment: On which device platform and platform version are you testing this code? [The documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/storereview/#storereviewrequestreview) for the API you're using states that the star-rating modal is unavailable for versions of iOS prior to 10.3.